# List-List to Range-List partitioning (Oracle DB)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-partitioning

I have little experience in OracleDB and I'm getting requested to change a table partitioning scheme from list-list to range-list (because the table is going to be created in a 9i server instead of an 11g one), however, I have the following doubt:

In a sample (production) script, they're creating a range-list (range from 1..2, list from 1..31):

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (id_month)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (id_day)
(
    PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (2)
    (
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP1 VALUES (1),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP2 VALUES (2),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP3 VALUES (3),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP4 VALUES (4),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP5 VALUES (5),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP6 VALUES (6),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP7 VALUES (7),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP8 VALUES (8),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP9 VALUES (9),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP10 VALUES (10),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP11 VALUES (11),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP12 VALUES (12),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP13 VALUES (13),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP14 VALUES (14),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP15 VALUES (15),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP16 VALUES (16),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP17 VALUES (17),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP18 VALUES (18),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP19 VALUES (19),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP20 VALUES (20),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP21 VALUES (21),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP22 VALUES (22),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP23 VALUES (23),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP24 VALUES (24),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP25 VALUES (25),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP26 VALUES (26),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP27 VALUES (27),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP28 VALUES (28),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP29 VALUES (29),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP30 VALUES (30),
        SUBPARTITION P1_SP31 VALUES (31)
    ),
    PARTITION P2 VALUES LESS THAN (3)
    (
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP1 VALUES (1),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP2 VALUES (2),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP3 VALUES (3),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP4 VALUES (4),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP5 VALUES (5),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP6 VALUES (6),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP7 VALUES (7),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP8 VALUES (8),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP9 VALUES (9),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP10 VALUES (10),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP11 VALUES (11),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP12 VALUES (12),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP13 VALUES (13),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP14 VALUES (14),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP15 VALUES (15),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP16 VALUES (16),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP17 VALUES (17),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP18 VALUES (18),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP19 VALUES (19),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP20 VALUES (20),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP21 VALUES (21),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP22 VALUES (22),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP23 VALUES (23),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP24 VALUES (24),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP25 VALUES (25),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP26 VALUES (26),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP27 VALUES (27),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP28 VALUES (28),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP29 VALUES (29),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP30 VALUES (30),
        SUBPARTITION P2_SP31 VALUES (31)
    )
)
/
```

Lists however, are created this way (in an example provided by a coworker):

```
PARTITION BY LIST (id_month)
SUBPARTITION BY LIST (id_day)
  SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp1 VALUES (1),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp2 VALUES (2),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp3 VALUES (3),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp4 VALUES (4),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp5 VALUES (5),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp6 VALUES (6),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp7 VALUES (7),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp8 VALUES (8),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp9 VALUES (9),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp10 VALUES (10),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp11 VALUES (11),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp12 VALUES (12),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp13 VALUES (13),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp14 VALUES (14),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp15 VALUES (15),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp16 VALUES (16),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp17 VALUES (17),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp18 VALUES (18),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp19 VALUES (19),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp20 VALUES (20),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp21 VALUES (21),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp22 VALUES (22),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp23 VALUES (23),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp24 VALUES (24),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp25 VALUES (25),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp26 VALUES (26),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp27 VALUES (27),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp28 VALUES (28),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp29 VALUES (29),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp30 VALUES (30),
    SUBPARTITION p1_sp31 VALUES (31)
  ) 
  (
    PARTITION p1 VALUES (1),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES (2),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES (3),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES (4),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES (5),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES (6),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES (7),
    PARTITION p8 VALUES (8),
    PARTITION p9 VALUES (9),
    PARTITION p10 VALUES (10),
    PARTITION p11 VALUES (11),
    PARTITION p12 VALUES (12),
    PARTITION p13 VALUES (13),
    PARTITION p14 VALUES (14),
    PARTITION p15 VALUES (15),
    PARTITION p16 VALUES (16),
    PARTITION p17 VALUES (17),
    PARTITION p18 VALUES (18),
    PARTITION p19 VALUES (19),
    PARTITION p20 VALUES (20),
    PARTITION p21 VALUES (21),
    PARTITION p22 VALUES (22),
    PARTITION p23 VALUES (23),
    PARTITION p24 VALUES (24)
  )
/
```

But since they can't create a list-list in 9i, they request me to convert it to a range-list partition.

Logic tells me I should do the first script, and repeat `PARTITION P1 VALUES LESS THAN (2)` from 2 to 32, leaving me with a huge script? is it the same? would it have the same effect? if not, what would, then? I've tried googling and looking for info about it but it isn't clear to me as an example like this is hard to find on the net, and I learn more by example than by reading long manuals and such.

Any kind of help is appreciated :)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your notation?  What does `1,24` mean and how does that differ from `1..24`?  Is `id_month` an integer between 1 and 24 (not 12)?

Comment: Ah right, my bad. That's taken from an Excel sheet. 1..24 is a range, 1,2,3,4,etc. I'll update the OP, sorry!

Comment: @JustinCave there! OP fixed :)

Comment: Your first script is the way to go.  Yes it's horrible but that's the cost of using old database versions. On the bright side at least you're using numbers.  When I had to do this I was replacing a list of strings, which made the ranges *really nasty* . [Read my blog on it](http://radiofreetooting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/oracle-10g-time-travellers-day.html)